# Simulate horizontal scroll in Windows with python

Tags: python, windows, onenote

as the title says, I'm looking for a way to simulate horizontal scrolling (specifically in OneNote). I know it is possible to do it in AutoHotKey with a script, but I'm trying to keep the program as localized as possible. I also know it is possible with PyAutoGui on mac and linux, but I've come up empty handed with anything related to windows. If you have any leads, I would greatly appreciate it:)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: My bad, I'm new to here, so thanks for info:) I've posted the answer in the responses, but can't tick it yet (Says I need to wait 2 days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar problem in the future, here's my solution:

```
import win32api, time, pyautogui as pag, keyboard
from win32con import *


running = True
lastX, lastY = pag.position()

while running:

    while keyboard.is_pressed("shift"):
        x, y = pag.position()
        if lastX!=x:
            win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL, 0, 0, x-lastX, 0) # Horizontal scrolling
            lastX=x

        if lastY!=y:
            win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, lastY-y, 0) # Vertical scrolling
            lastY=y
```

Hope this can help anyone in the future:)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 already has an out-of-the-box shortcut for horizontal scroll:
Hold Shift down and use the mouse wheel for side scroll. (This shortcut seems to also work on Ubuntu und MacOS)

Considering this shortcut exists it is possible to emulate it with PyAutoGui like so

```
import pyautogui
offset = 100
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.scroll(offset)
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```